# Is there a way to change the displayed desktop in Mission Control?

Tags: macos, mission-control

I'd like to be able to change the displayed desktop in Mission Control without actually exiting Mission control.  For example, if I'm on desktop 1 and I go into Mission Control, I see all of the applications in that desktop along with thumbnails for the other desktops.  Can I view the applications in the one of the other desktops without having to click on it and leave Mission Control and then go back into Mission Control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key and click on the desktop.

The desktop you clicked on will slide into view.

Comment: This is exactly the functionality I had in mind, but Paul's suggestion of swiping is probably what I will actually end up doing.  Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 4):

Push <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd> It also can be done by swiping if you have a Magic Mouse or Trackpad.

Comment: My only comment is to wonder why I didn't try swiping. :-)

Comment: Heh, so much to learn in OS X.